# Jenkins with Azure active directory authentication: REST API access not working with Bearer token

Tags: azure, tomcat, jenkins, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I need to access Jenkins REST API using python code. Need some guidance about the correct approach.

I have hosted jenkins v2.176.1 in apache tomcat with SSL enabled.
I have configured Azure AD authentication based on [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+AD+Plugin).
I am able to login using my Azure AD credentials in browser and access the REST API of jenkins.

When i try to access the REST API from curl or postman based on the samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) i am able to get the access token but jenkins rest api(with `Authorization: Bearer [access_token]` in the header) response shows as unauthorized.

The API permissions configured are : Under Azure Active directory graph, Group.Read.All and User.Read.All .
The only way by which i can access the REST API from postman is:

**Step 1**: In the postman Authorization tab with oauth2 option --> Get new access token --> grant_type as `"Authorization Code"`. The response contains access_token, refresh_token and `id_token`.
This sets the microsoft login related cookies in postman.
**Step 2**: Do a GET request to `https://[jenkinsHost]/securityRealm/commenceLogin` with the param "id_token:id_token"(obtained from previous step)
It returns a HTML response(200) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Working...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://[jenkins_host]/jenkins/securityRealm/finishLogin">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi....." />
        <input type="hidden" name="session_state" value="1b151d4a-3318-49b5-a653-18260501ba6a" />
        <noscript>
            <p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </noscript>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This sets the jenkins cookie with `JSESSIONID`.
**Step 3**: POST request to : `https://[jenkins_host]/jenkins/securityRealm/finishLogin` with the param `id_token` whose value is available from the previous response.(Skipping this step returns 403 response from REST API even though the cookie was set from Step 2)
**Step 4**: GET request to Jenkins REST API without any other parameters/headers works fine.

Can someone guide me with the correct flow to access the REST API or if what i am doing(using cookies) is the right way ?

Comment: Please refer the solution posted in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969864/login-using-sharepoint-client-web-part/60972479#60972479